# Why are searches on 2dsphere indexes so slow in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, elasticsearch, mongodb-query

Here's an example of a geo-$near query from a geospatially-indexed collection of ~2 million documents that takes almost a half a second to locate documents within a tiny 200-meter radius.

```
rs-[SNIP]:PRIMARY> db.photograph.find({'!geo': { $near: { $geometry: { coordinates: [-71.091246, 42.361474], type: 'Point' }, $maxDistance: 200 }}}).limit(100).explain();
{    
  "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",    
  "isMultiKey" : false,
  "n" : 100,
  "nscannedObjects" : 3914,
  "nscanned" : 59115,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3914,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 59115,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 462,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 418,
  "indexBounds" : {

  },
  "server" : "[SNIP]",
  "filterSet" : false
}
```

My questions:

- Why is it scanning 59115 objects? Even if I set $maxDistance to 0.1 or 0.01 meters, which of course both give 0 results, it still takes 400 ms and scans 50K objects. Can I tune the geohashing algorithm so that it uses finer bucket sizes and doesn't need to scan that much?
- Would a 2d index be better than a 2dsphere index for this use case? (The legacy 2d index has tunable hash precision according to the docs.)
- Would manually implementing a geohash as a range index be better to reduce 'nscanned'?
- Why is indexOnly false in this case? I *do* have an index on '!geo' ...
- Would ElasticSearch perform significantly better? I don't need ACID consistency; eventual consistency is enough and what I need most is raw search speed and the ability to serve a large number of concurrent users issuing geospatial queries simultaneously. The number of documents may grow into the billions; 99% of the time I'll be querying for "the most recent 100 objects within a 200-meter radius".